# How to make After Effects UI button to respond immediately while the script is processing

Tags: user-interface, progress-bar, extendscript, after-effects, cancel-button

When I run this code in ExtendScript Toolkit (Target app - After Effects CC 2015) the cancel button is not responding until the progress bar has finished.

I would like to make it work so that the cancel button would respond immediately.

I know that pressing the "Esc" key works immediately, so it should be possible to make the cancel button work as well.

```js
testWindow = new Window ("palette", "Processing:", undefined);
pb = testWindow.add("progressBar",undefined, 0);
cancelButton = testWindow.add("button", undefined, "Cancel");

testWindow.show();

cancelButton.onClick = function(){
    alert("Cancel");
    }

i = 1;  

while (i <= 1000000) {  
    pb.value = Math.round(100*i/1000000);
    testWindow.update();
    i++
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need promises in AE extend script. I don't know if that's a thing or if there's a library out there. But the magic words you're looking for are "Javascript Promise"

Answer (score 0):

I think it has always been so: while a script is running, the user interface  is on hold and non responding. Adding a Cancel button somewhere cannot work.

The only way i know for a user to cancel the execution of script is the ESC key.